# How to reduce this ODE $ x''+x=f(t)$ to affine ODE of first order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

let $f$ be a real valued continous function such that $$x''+x=f(t) $$ , It is easy to reduce this ODE to first ODE just multiplying its sides by the term $2x'$ and integrating yields :$$\frac12 x'^2+\frac{x^2}{2}=2F(t)$$, $F(t)+c$ is the antiderivative of  $x'f(t) $ but what i have  got is not affine ODE ?

**Source**:I have got this question in Doctorat exams (Algeria 2016) .(see the attached picture exo 1 . first question)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the left-hand side, we can find the homogeneous part of the solution $x''+x=0$ giving $x(t) = C_1 \cos(t) + C_2 \sin(t)$. So try setting $x(t) = u(t) \cos(t)$. Then

$$x'(t) = -\sin(t) u(t) + \cos(t) u'(t)$$
$$x''(t) = -\cos(t) u(t) - 2 \sin(t) u'(t) + \cos(t) u''(t)$$
So
$$x''(t) + x(t) = -\cos(t) u(t) - 2\sin(t) u'(t) + \cos(t) u''(t) +\cos(t) u(t) =f(t)$$
So now we have an equation
$$ u''(t)\cos(t) - 2\sin(t) u'(t) = f(t)$$
We can treat this equation like a first order linear equation in $u'(t)$. Find a multiplier $\rho(t)$ and then integrate the equation to put it into the form

$$u'(t) = \frac{1}{\rho(t)}\int \rho(t) f(t) \sec(t) dt$$

Answer (score 0):

$x''+x=f(t)$

Using reduction of order.

Let $y=u(t)\sin{t}$.

$y'=u'\sin t + u \cos t$

$y''=u''\sin t + 2u'\cos t -u\sin t$

$y''+y=u''\sin t + 2u'\cos t=f(t)$

$u''+2u'\cot t=f(t)\csc t$

$d(u'\sin^2 t)=f(t)\sin t$

$u'\sin^2 t=\int f(t)\sin t dt$

$u'=\csc^2 t\int f(t)\sin t dt$

Integrate to find $u$, then $x=u\sin t.$

Answer (score 0):

We only need to let $x'=y$ and rewrite the equation in the **affine** form
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}'=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ f(t)\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: I have tried this but id dosn't work , what about x ? pleas i need more detail for your matricial form and this what i need exactly

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?